# One testNG test case is failing from a set of test cases, could not identify what the issue is?

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, testng

I am new to learning Selenium WebDriver and testNG. I was trying to learn some testNG annotations via below set of test cases, however one test case is always failing and I could not figure out what the error is?

Also, I tried to search in the existing question but could not find which matches with my issue. So here I'll explain what I am trying to achieve:

1. I have created three classes which contains `testNG` annotations test cases. Classes names are: `testingNG`, `testingNG1` and `testingNG2`.
2. Then I have created a testNg xml file so that these test cases can be executed as a suit.
3. I have also created one properties file (`paths.properties`) which stores some xpaths which I want to use in `test2` of `testingNG` class.
4. When I am running this xml file as a suit, `test2` of `testingNG` class is always failing, however eclipse do not show any syntax error and I could not understand what the issue is.

## First class:testigNG

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class testingNG {

    @Test
    public void test1()
    {
        System.out.println("first NG test case");
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        Properties pro=new Properties();
        FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream (System.getProperty("C:\\Users\\SumitKumar.Dubey\\workspace\\My_testNG\\src\\paths.properties"));
        pro.load(fis);
        System.out.println("Login link xpath: "+pro.getProperty("DLJ_Login_Button"));
        FirefoxDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.dsij.in/");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(pro.getProperty("DLJ_Login_Button"))).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(pro.getProperty("DLJ_Login_Username"))).sendKeys("dubey_sumit");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(pro.getProperty("DLJ_Login_Pwd"))).sendKeys("0VUoUEMGpiC");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(pro.getProperty("DLJ_click_login"))).click();
    }
}


Second class: testingNG1
=========================

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class testingNG1 {

    @Test
    public void test4()
    {
        System.out.println("fourth NG test case from testNG1 class");
    }
}
```

## Third class: testingNG2

```
import java.io.Console;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class testingNG2 {
    FirefoxDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();

    @Test (priority=1)
    public void site_navigate()
    {

        driver.get("http://demoqa.com/");
        System.out.println("print when ulr is entered!");


    }
    @Test (priority=2)
    public void click_about_us()
    {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='http://demoqa.com/about-us/']")).click();
        System.out.println("print when ulr is entered!");
        //driver.getPageSource().contains("About us");  
        if(driver.getPageSource().contains("About us"))
        {
        System.out.println("Text is Present");
        }
        else
        {
        System.out.println("Text is not Present");
        }
    }
    @AfterTest
    public void close_browser()
    {
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

## testNG xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">

  <test name="Test1">
    <classes>
      <class name="testingNG1"/>
    </classes>
  </test>

  <test name="Test2">
    <classes>
      <class name="testingNG2"/>
    </classes>
  </test>

  <test name="Test3">
    <classes>
      <class name="testingNG"/>
    </classes>
  </test>

</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

## paths.properties file:

```
#Dalal Street Login
DLJ_Login_Button=//a[@id='dnn_dnnLogin_enhancedLoginLink']
DLJ_Login_Username=//input[@id='dnn_ctr5070_Login_Login_DNN_txtUsername']
DLJ_Login_Pwd=//input[@id='dnn_ctr5070_Login_Login_DNN_txtPassword']
DLJ_click_login=//input[@id='dnn_ctr5070_Login_Login_DNN_cmdLogin']
```

Here `test2` of `testingNG` class is failing which uses the properties file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 1):

I think the properties are not loaded because of this line:

```
FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream (System.getProperty("C:\\Users\\SumitKumar.Dubey\\workspace\\My_testNG\\src\\paths.properties"));
```

Please remove the System.getProperty() from this line and specify the path in a File object as shown below.

```
FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream (new File("C:\\Users\\SumitKumar.Dubey\\workspace\\My_testNG\\src\\paths.properties"));
```

Comment: Thank you Jaganathan. I tried and it worked. If it is possible could you please elaborate the concept bit more? Actually I read some tutorials and based upon that tried this way.

Comment: If you store the path to the properties file in a System property say **testng.properties.file.path** , it can be retrieved using `System.getProperty("testng.properties.file.path");` In your case I believe you don't have a System property, but just the path to the properties file. So, we are just loading the properties directly from the file path.

Comment: Yeah that's correct, its just the path to the properties file. Thank you so much for prompt response :)